# I am getting breaking point error in this c++ program of mine,have a look. compiler visual c++ 2010

Tags: c++

```
error snapshot : https://rapidshare.com/files/3201989698/Capture5.JPG

code :



#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int ch_m;

HANDLE hConsole;

class budget
{
public :
    float balance;

    string due_name,loan_name;
    int  year,month;
    float due_pay,loan_given;//due_pay due to be paid 


    budget()
    {
        balance=0;
        month=1;
        due_name="NO BODY";
        loan_name="SAFE";
        year=0;            
        balance = 0;
        due_pay=0;
        loan_given=0;

    }
    char get_data();
    void show_data();
    void budget_menu();
    void balance_menu();

    int yr()
    {
        return(year);

    }

    int mont()
    {
        return month;
    }




};

void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
    COORD dwCursorPosition;
    cout.flush();
    dwCursorPosition.X=x;
    dwCursorPosition.Y=y;
    hConsoleOutput=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition
    (hConsoleOutput,dwCursorPosition);
}

char budget :: get_data()
{
  char ch_b;
    gotoxy(5,2);
    cout<<"Enter Month                                                           :";
    cin>>month;
    gotoxy(5,4);
    cout<<"Enter year                                                            :";
    cin>>year;
    gotoxy(5,6);
    cout<<"Enter your balance for the current month and year in Rs               :"; 
    cin>>balance;
     do
       {
           gotoxy(6,9);
           cout<<"Continue adding records?(y/n)\n";
           cin>>ch_b;
       }while(tolower(ch_b)!='n'&&tolower(ch_b)!='y');


       return ch_b;


}



void budget :: show_data()
{

    gotoxy(5,2);
    cout<<"Month                                                           :"<<month;
    gotoxy(5,4);
    cout<<"Year                                                            :"<<year;

    gotoxy(5,6);
    cout<<"Your balance for the current month and year in RS               :"<<balance; 

  _getch();
}


void budget:: budget_menu()
{



    system("cls");
    gotoxy(12,5);



    cout<<"---------------------------------------";
    gotoxy(12,6);
    cout<<"Budget Menu";
    gotoxy(12,7);
    cout<<"---------------------------------------";
    gotoxy(12,10);  
    cout<<"1) Balance";
    gotoxy(12,12);
    cout<<"2) Loan Given";
    gotoxy(12,14);
    cout<<"3) Due to be paid";
    gotoxy(12,16);
    cout<<"4) Exit";

   gotoxy(14,17);
    cout<<"Enter your choice\n";
    cin>>ch_m;


    switch(ch_m)
    {
    case 1:  
        balance_menu();
        break;
    default:
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(15,8);
        cout<<"Wrong Input!!";

    }




}


void write_balance()
 {
system("cls");
 budget b;
 ofstream f1;
 f1.open("balance.dat",ios::app|ios::binary);
 char ch;
 do{
        ch = b.get_data();
        f1.write((char*)&b,sizeof(b));
   }while(tolower(ch)=='y');

 f1.close();


 }



 void read_balance()                //PROBLEM AFTER ENTERING THIS FUNCTION
     {
         system("cls");
       budget b;
    ifstream f1;
    f1.open("balance.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
    while(f1.read((char*)&b,sizeof(b)))
    { b.show_data();
     }

   system("cls");
       cout<<"No More Records To Display!!";
    getch();
    f1.close();

     }



void budget :: balance_menu()
{
    int ch_bm;//balance menu choice

    char coni;//continue?
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(12,6);
    cout<<"1) Add current month and year balance";
    gotoxy(12,7);
    cout<<"2) Modify a balance";
    gotoxy(12,8);
    cout<<"3) Search a balance";
    gotoxy(12,9);
    cout<<"4)Delete a Record";
    gotoxy(12,10);
    cout<<"5) Display all records";
    gotoxy(12,11);
    cout<<"6) Back to previous menu";
    gotoxy(12,12);
    cout<<"7) Exit";
    gotoxy(14,15);
    cout<<"Enter your choice\n";
    cin>>ch_bm;
    switch(ch_bm)
    {
    case 1 :write_balance();
        break;
    case 5:
        read_balance();
        break;
    default :
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(15,8);
        cout<<"Wrong Input!!";
    }

    if(ch_bm!=6)
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(15,8);
        cout<<"Continue?";
        cin>>coni;
    if(tolower(coni)=='y')
     {
        balance_menu();
     }
    }

getch();
}








void main()

{

    system("cls");

    budget b;
    b.budget_menu();


    _getch();
}
```

first go to option 1/1 to create the file and then 1/5 to read the contents where you will get breaking point error....
till now i have included only read and write option .

It has been 3 weeks.. i m stuck here

i have tried a lot of things

My code is working fine in turbo c++ but not in vc++
this code is to keep data of one's budget. function having problem is highlighted using comment.

Comment: In the line "while(f1.read((char*)&b,sizeof(b)))", you are reading a set of bytes to a class which contains a string member. Indiscriminately setting a set of bytes to a string object would initialize various internal members of this string(e.g : the string buffer/size of the buffer) in an unwanted way. This could result in unpredictable results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way you're trying to use this site isn't really the way it works. This isn't a personally debugging service. You're expected to ask questions that are not only specifically useful to you right now, but might also be generally useful to others who arrive here by search engine in the future. Your question is specifically geared to your specific code. Trim it down until you have the minimum required to exhibit the problem, and then it will be easier to ask a more general question.

Comment: If you've spent *three weeks* working to get this code working, you don't need someone to fix your code. You need to learn general debugging and problem-solving techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my review:

1. Use `double` not `float` unless smaller variable size is needed.
2. Assign `0.0` to floating point quantities.  Append with 'F' if for
   floating point.
3. Prefer one variable definition per line.  Makes for easier development and 
   maintenance.  The cost in build time is very negligible.
4. Prefer to use initialization list in constructors, such as `:
   balance(0.0), //...`
5. Be consistent in your `return` statements.  Parenthesis are not
   required.
6. Do you *need* to have cursor positioning?  It is a difficult issue
   in Windows.
7. The C++ default I/O streams may not be compatibile with Windows
   console positioning.
8. You are not storing records.  The last iteration will always
   overwrite the previous record.
9. Why do you need to return the operator's response from `get_data`?
10. Definitely get rid of the cursor positioning.  It is getting in the
     way of your development.  Add it back in, if necessary, after your
     program is working correctly and is robust.
11. You don't give the operator a chance to correct the selection and
     try again.  *Not good*
12. Prefer not to use binary I/O, especially when writing structures
     and classes to files.  If the class or structure layout changes or
     the compiler inserts padding between fields your reading may not be
     assigned correctly.  Also, verify your data in the file is going to
     be more difficult.  I suggest using one text line per record and
     each field separated by a tab, comma or other delimiter.  This
     allows you to import your data into other applications, such a
     spreadsheet, for verification.  Text is a lot easier to verify than
     binary data.
13. Prefer to have I/O methods in your class / object.  That way you
     can make one easy statement like `file << my_budget;`
14. If you didn't use x,y positioning, you could declare the menu as
     one constant text literal and output it (much easier and faster)
     than having to display one line at a time.  Easier to modify and
     maintain too.
15. The `main` function returns `int`, always.  Use `return
     EXIT_SUCCESS;` if necessary.
16. In your methods, the `budget` variables are local and will
     disappear upon return from the method.  Reference the class
     variable instead.
17. Always check for I/O errors.  This could be where your issue is.
18. Pause the console before clearing it.  Try this:
     `cin.ignore(100000, "\n");`